# str_replace remove words from title

Tags: php

I have a site that reviews movies (DVD/Blu-ray, etc.)So every review in a particular category will have (Blu-ray) after the title, another will have DVD and so forth. i.e. Avengers: Infinity War (Blu-ray). I want to trim the format of the disc (Blu-ray) from the page title and I have this code, but it's not working. Wasn't sure what the issue was.

```
<span style="color: #ffffff">About <?php if (in_category('5447') ):?>
<?php
echo str_replace("(Blu-ray)","&nbsp;","<?php the_title(); ?>");
?>
</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So, in essence, I can grab the title and it will read:
Avengers: Infinity War (Blu-ray)

but I want it to read:
Avengers: Infinity War

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_title()` will directly output the title - for your purpose in a string manipulation, you need to use `get_the_title()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/

you also have some php syntax error;

try to use:

```
<?php
echo str_replace( "(Blu-ray)","&nbsp;", get_the_title() );
?>
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. I don't know how, but I won't argue with results. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you have mistake hire :

```
echo str_replace("(Blu-ray)","&nbsp;","<?php the_title(); ?>");

should be : echo str_replace( "(Blu-ray)", "", get_the_title() );
```

1 - the_title() echo directly the title, you cannot do enything whit the title.

2- when call the str_replace() dot put inside php tags ;)